# Process.StandardOutput.Read() hangs on empty buffer

Tags: c#, process, io-redirection

My goal is to be able to asynchronously read the stdout stream of a process character-at-a-time.  My simplified but still failing code is below.  Read reads the characters fine until all of them have been read, but when it then goes back for another character it never returns.  I'm using Win 8.1 Pro 64-bit, VS2013 Ultimate, and building for .NET 4.5.

Thanks,
Ray

```
  public static void RunIt()
  {
     Process process = new Process();
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\temp\\C1A7E1.exe";
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
     process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
     process.Start();

     string textString = string.Empty;
     for (; ; )
     {
        int outputCharInt;
        if ((outputCharInt = process.StandardOutput.Read()) != -1)
           textString += (char)outputCharInt;
        else
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna asynchronously read the standard output, you have to handle `Prcess.OutputDataReceived` event and use `Process.BeginOutputReadLine()` method as follows:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("process file");
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
...
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine(); // Starts the asynchronous read

private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

As a reference see: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Diagnostics.Process.OutputDataReceived%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)

Comment: Arin, unless I am mistaken, the event only gets called when a complete line is sent to stdout.  This is not suitable for my purpose since I need to read character-at-a-time.  Ray

Comment: Your code has a little bug, if it reaches the end of stream you never break the loop! so it goes forever, in the else part use `break`. I don't know if I've realized your question right, but anyhow in your case your loop never ends!

Comment: You are correct, but I did mention that my code is a simplified version of the real code, which does have a meaningful way to exit the loop.  The code I provided above was merely to demonstrate the bare-bones code that was failing.  Incidentally, I was able to get my code to work much better by first calling process.StandardOutput.Peek() to see if a character is actually present, and only calling Read() if so.  Apparently Read() does not return -1 if no character is present under some circumstances, but instead never returns at all, or at least that's the way it works in my code sample.

Comment: OK but without seeing your actual code it's hard to find the problem and I've no idea what kind of data you'e expecting and what is the output of the process.